# adding custom button to existing site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im trying to add custom buttons to a existing site using Greasemonkey.
The problem is that this site has no ID for html elements and repeated classes. Also everything is inside tables!

This is the structure of the site. The arrow is where I want to add the new buttons:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjwUb.png

This is what I have so far:

```
$(".embedded table tbody tr").find("td:last")
.append(newtd);
```

(where newtd is the custom button)

but since there are several element with that class, i can't tell jquery which one I should add the button to and right now it appears inside every table with the "embbeded" class

New buttons should be added next to the existing IMG
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOAYC.png

Is there anyway I can do that?

Comment: if there are many 'embedded' classes, which one do you want to add the button to?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/tv5pL.png Next to the IMG button (which is named embedded class too)

Comment: I think this would help
http://i.imgur.com/VKky7.png

I forgot there are two more classes there. Now it should be easier I think. But not for me because I'm just starting with javascript/jquery

Answer (score 0):

Just use a regular CSS3 [`nth-child`](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) selector:

```
$(".embedded:nth-child(7) td:last-child").append(newtd);
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I guess it's because it's a forum and EVERY post has the embedded class. So maybe now it's embedded number 7, or 15 but later it will be number 20.

Comment: @martn - So how do you (as a human) identify where you want that button to appear? What's the criteria for having the button there?

Comment: you're right, I should've explained.I want to add a button next to the "IMG"
http://i.imgur.com/tv5pL.png

Comment: @martn - Do you want to add it next to every "img" button on the site?

Comment: No, just in that reply form. It would be easy if that form had some type of id but it doesn't. The whole site is just tables, td, and tr without anything else. (except for the embedded class)

Comment: I think this would help
http://i.imgur.com/VKky7.png

I forgot there are two more classes there.

Comment: @martn - Why don't you use `[name=img]`?

Comment: because name=img is inside the td class=embedded.
Every td Class=embedded in that screencapture has a button inside.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".embedded table tbody tr").find("td:last").eq(3)
.append(newtd);
```

Where 3 is the 3rd element.